# what is the meaning of yh = [ [ ] ] * num in python

Tags: python

what is the meaning of `yh = [ [ ] ] * num` in python.
and list in a list?
is it mean when num = 3  yh = [ [[]],[[]],[[]] ]?
the full code down below to calculate an Pascal's triangle.

```
def main():
    num = int(input('Number of rows: '))
    yh = [[]] * num
    for row in range(len(yh)):
        yh[row] = [None] * (row + 1)
        for col in range(len(yh[row])):
            if col == 0 or col == row:
                yh[row][col] = 1
            else:
                yh[row][col] = yh[row - 1][col] + yh[row - 1][col - 1]
            print(yh[row][col], end='\t')
        print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If you can't read the python docs, experimentation is a good way to answer questions like this for yourself. Open python, and try `print([[]])` and `print([[]]*5)` and so on.

Comment: You can just print(yh) to see what it means. Lists in a list

Comment: This generates a list with `num` empty lists. However, it should be noted that these empty lists are the same object. Changing any one will cause the same changes to other lists.

Comment: Notice how you have a 2d list with only one inner list and you’re multiplying it by a number read in as “ Number of rows”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[[]]` is a list containing a single empty list.

[List multiplication](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) creates a new list with the same elements repeated that number of times. So `[[]] * num` will create a list of `num` elements in length, where each element is the same empty list. That's generally unlikely to be what you want - because all the elements refer to the *same* list any mutations you apply to it will be seen in all places. In this example it doesn't matter - the code never accesses those items. You could do `[None] * num` instead and the code still works.

For an example of the hazards here, consider this example:

```
>>> sequence = [[]] * 3
>>> print(sequence)
[[], [], []]
>>> sequence[0].append(77)
>>> print(sequence)
[[77], [77], [77]]
```

This is the much the same as if you'd done:

```
>>> empty = []
>>> sequence = [empty, empty, empty]
>>> print(sequence)
[[], [], []]
>>> empty.append(33)
>>> print(sequence)
[[33], [33], [33]]
```

Comment: To avoid that hazard, you may wish to generate a list of empty lists with something like `[[] for _ in range(3)]`